# Why is CoreLocation (Mac OS X) not remembering my choice to allow its use?

Tags: macos, cocoa, core-location

I'm probably being very stupid, but I can't work out why the following is happening:

I have an app on Mac OS X which uses CoreLocation.  Below is the the relevant code:

It asks for permission to use my location every time it launches and never remembers that I have already granted use of location data.

The app never appears in the 'Privacy' Preference pane.

Am I missing something?

Thanks.

```
#pragma mark - General Instance Methods

- (void)determineLocation
{
    if (self.locationManager)
    {
        DDLogWarn(@"determinLocation called, but we already have a locationManager instance variable...");
        DDLogWarn(@"This is a bug.");
    }

    self.currentlocationName = @"Location unknown";
    if (![CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled])
    {
        DDLogWarn(@"Location Services not enabled.");
        [self fallBackToHardcodedLocation];
        return;
    }

    //  Location services are available.
    self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    self.locationManager.delegate = self;


    //  Coarse-grained location accuracy required.
    self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyThreeKilometers;
    self.locationManager.distanceFilter = 1000; // meters - 1km
    [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}



#pragma mark - Location Manager Delegate Methods


- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didChangeAuthorizationStatus:(CLAuthorizationStatus)status
{
    DDLogVerbose(@"Our authorisation to use the location manager has changed.");
    switch (status) {
        case kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined:
            DDLogError(@"LocationManager Authorisation status not determined. (User hasn't chosen yet)");
            break;

        case kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorized:
            DDLogVerbose(@"We are now authorised for locationServices.");
            [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
            break;

        case kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied:
            DDLogWarn(@"LocationManager: We are now explicitly denied!");
            [self.locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
            break;

        case kCLAuthorizationStatusRestricted:
            DDLogWarn(@"LocationManager We are now restricted! (not authorised - perhaps due to parental controls...)");
            [self.locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
{
    //  Main callback for location discovery..§

    CLLocation* location = [locations lastObject];
    NSDate* eventDate = location.timestamp;
    NSTimeInterval howRecent = [eventDate timeIntervalSinceNow];
    if (abs(howRecent) < 15.0)
    {
        // Event is recent. Do something with it.
        if (location.horizontalAccuracy > 1000)
        {
            DDLogWarn(@"Location Accuracy is worse than 1km, discarding...");
        } else {
            [self updateLocation:location];
        }
        return;
    }

    DDLogWarn(@"Stale location data...");
    [self updateLocation:location];
}
```

It always asks permission: (kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined appears to always be the case.)

```
 2015-02-07 01:03:36:127 Central Heating[2260:30b] LocationManager Authorisation status not determined. (User hasn't chosen yet)
```

[image: CoreLocation permission always asked]
(Dialog text: "Central Heating" would like to use your current location. Your location is needed for weather forecasting. [Don't allow] [OK])

Comment: Is your app signed? I'm not specifically familiar with CoreLocation, but most such things identify apps by their signature, and if the app isn't signed there's no way to tell it's the same one you granted access to earlier.

Comment: Thanks very much.  The app wasn't signed.  Signing it appears to solve the issue.  If you put your comment as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Gordon Mentioned, this issue is resolved by signing the application.